# What does Kensei Muguruma's bankai do?

Tags: bleach

His *shikai*, **Tachikaze**, is a wind-based zanpakutou that can launch long-range, string-like, blades that slices enemies. But what special abilities does **Tekken Tachikaze**, Kensei Muguruma's *bankai*, possess?

Answer (score 3):

It was confirmed in chapter 560, taken from  [Bleach Wikia](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Kensei_Muguruma#cite_note-70):

> It appears to greatly augment his strength, as he is able to create a
>   large explosion upon attacking. This is due to the fact that in this
>   form the power of his Bankai is transferred to the knuckle blades. The
>   bursting power continues to hit his opponent endlessly as long as his
>   fists are touching his opponent.

Comment: Could you specify what chapter number you're referring to in your answer so that it will be remain understandable to future visitors?

Comment: He's referring to the chapter 560.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia:

> Kensei's bankai is named Tekken Tachikaze (鐡拳・断地風?, lit. Iron Fist Earth-Severing Wind). The combat knife transforms into two bladed, bronze knuckle-like weapons known as tiger claws in each hand that are connected by a long fabric-like material that wraps around and up his arms like bandages and form a small arc above his head. Its abilities are unknown.

Comment: So it wasn't revealed yet. :/ Thanks kuwaly! +1